# Where did I go wrong in this linear programming problem?

Tags: word-problem, operations-research

> **Question:** A camping supply company makes backpacks in two models, *journey* and *trek*. The journey model requires $4$ hours of labor and generates a profit of $40$ dollars. The trek model requires $6$ hours of labor and generates a profit of $80$ dollars. The company needs to profit at least $\$400$ per week. Their distributor will accept no more than $4$ trek backpacks and no more than $15$ journey backpacks per week. How many of each type of backpack should the company make to minimize the number of hours of labor?

---

**My Attempt:**

I let $x$ be the number journey and $y$ be the number of trek backpacks produced during the week. Thus, we have

$$40x+80y\geq 400\\0\leq x\leq 4\\ 0\leq y\leq 15\tag1$$

And an objective function of $4x+6y$. Thus, the minimized/maximized points are $(0,5),(0,15),(4,3),(4,15)$ and I got $0,5$ as the answer. Meaning $5$ treks and no journeys.

But the problem was wrong. It was supposed to be $(4,3)$.

*Where did I go wrong?*

Comment: The objective function must be  Min 4x + 6y, with 40x+80y>=400, 0<y<=4 and 0<=x<=15.  You messed up the last two constraints with notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mix up the constraints. It should be
$$
0\le x\le 15,\quad 0\le y\le 4.
$$